# How i select one file to run on eclipse? Im using eclipse to learn C

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

i have tried build project, build all, and it doesn't show the File, only show the project.

I'm running this file on eclipse, its a C algorithm.
[image]

I want to run only the file with the name secao02-exercicio... but doesn't appear in run, what i do?

Comment: I’m assuming that eclipse by default names the binary the same as the project. Makes sense as you mostly have projects with more than one file in them. I’m sure you can customize the binary name somewhere in the settings though.

Comment: Maybe you should learn 'c' and 'eclipse' separately? Eclise is very customizable and requires some konwledge of building 'c' porgrams before using it.

Comment: Look into the (pseudo) directory "Binaries" and launch your program.

Comment: how i do this @the

Comment: Right click on the executable you wish to run, "Run as...", "Local C/C++ Appliaction". You could also create a configuration, see the menu "Run -> Run Configurations...". You should consider to read Eclipse's help pages, professional IDEs commonly need a bit of learning before you get pace. If you're a beginner and want something simple, use a simple IDE. Or even better, learn to use the command line.